# Center svg to mean line text

Tags: css, svg, position, center

I would like to center my svg element to something called: 'mean line' text.
Mean line text is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_line
Here's my example: [image]

Additionaly, how to remove white space between path and svg? Path have good size but svg add some white space to my icon ;(

Comment: use alignment-baseline attribute